# raspberry pi camera streaming won't start from php

Tags: php, python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi

Lately I've been playing with R-Pi. Now I'm trying to stream with the Raspberry pi b+ and camera.
I have a basic website in php from where I give commands to camera (Start - Stop streaming).

The problem is that when I press Start Streaming , the RED led from camera will light for a sec then it's going off.
When I choose to run the stream from command line(terminal) , it works.

Here's my script :

> #!/bin/sh
>     raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 600 -h 400 -fps 12 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264

And here's my php file where do I call the shell script:

> $trimite = shell_exec('sudo sh streaming.sh');

Any ideeas? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I took a look at your project. It is nice but I'm using VLC player and shell script that runs in php.
I think it's about how php works because when I write to serial from webserver , it works.

Comment: I don't think you can privilege escalate.

Comment: I did succed to run the script.
Seems like somehow my script was something like : sudo sudo script...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this could be being caused by a permissions error. Run the command `sudo chmod +x streaming.sh`

If that does not fix the problem, (assuming you have a webserver running apache) run "sudo a2enmod" in terminal, then `sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/cgi-bin` then restart apache (sudo service apache restart)

---

Note:
If error "could not write permissions, directory does not exist" occurs, you will need to run command 'sudo mkdir /usr/lib/cgi-bin/' in terminal

---

Create a cgi script to call bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
echo ""
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo "<html><head><title>Light on"
echo "</title>"
echo "</head><body>"
echo "$(bash /home/pi/streaming.sh) #this calls the shell script"
echo "</body></html>"
```

Then you must save this file as /usr/lib/cgi-bin/first.cgi and assign it permissions with "sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/cgi-bin/first.cgi" Assuming that your apache server is set up correctly (Various guides can be found about enabling the cgi module correctly, if a2enmod did not work properly), you should now be able to go to the web browser on another LAN machine and browse to http://IPofRPI/cgi-bin/first.cgi.

The script should execute. Congratulations!

If the script does not execute, you can read up about CGI and apache modules online and see what is wrong with your scripts.

I had kind of the same problem a while back and that question can be found here: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461124/cgi-script-not-executing-bash-commands-such-as-cp)

I hope this helps you, or someone else :)