# CGI script not executing bash commands such as 'CP'

Tags: linux, bash, apache, raspberry-pi, cgi

I have a web server (apache2) set up to execute files with a .cgi file extension. This works for some commands. However, I need it to copy the file /var/www/on.html to the location of /var/www/a1.html.

I am using Debian Linux. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo "<html><head><title>Light on"
echo "</title>"
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; url=http://86.11.221.243' />"
echo "</head><body>"
echo "$(gpio mode 8 out) #this turns the light on"
echo "$(cp /var/www/on.html /var/www/a1.html)"
echo "</body></html>"
```

I am using cp to copy a html webpage with a green background to replace a file which has a black background. This is used to indicate the status of the LED a1 (column a row 1).

Comment: Please explain why do you do a `cp /var/www/on.html /var/www/a1.html` by editing your question...

Comment: The line with `<meta`  is probably missing a quote

Comment: <meta missing quote unintentional. Is there on actual script.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve and motivate it (explain why the `cp`)

Comment: I am using the CP to copy a webpage named on.html (with just green background) to the new destination of /var/www/a1.html in order to indicate to the users that the LED is lit up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> echo "$(cp /var/www/on.html /var/www/a1.html)"
> ```

The `$(` ... `)`  is running the command inside the parenthesis and is replaced by the *output* (to *stdout*) of that command. A successful `cp` does not have any output. A failing `cp` is giving an error message to *stderr*, not *stdout*. In both cases the effect is that of `echo ""`  (outputs an empty line, i.e. a single newline), with perhaps an additional side effect of copying the file. And that copy is run as the `www-data` user (the one running your web server) .... so would fail if `/var/www/` is not writable by it (on my system `/var/www/` is owned by `root:root` and is not world writable, so `www-data` cannot write in it).

So, no need to have `echo` on that particular `cp` line. You could replace it with `cp /var/www/on.html /var/www/a1.html ; logger cp got $?` (but using `cp` is not very good, see below)

BTW, the `cp`  is not an atomic operation. What would happen if two such CGI processes are running concurrently is not exactly defined. Perhaps you want to force a hard link with `ln -f`  (that *is* an atomic operation) instead of `cp`

You could make `/var/www/` owned by `www-data`, or world-writable. In both cases, that is a security hole (which you might afford on a dedicated *internal* webserver, accessible only from your home network). If you can afford replacing `/var/www/on.html` and `/var/www/a1.html` by `/var/www/mydir/on.html` and `/var/www/mydir/a1.html` (so change the HTML code refering to them) you could simply have a `/var/www/mydir/` directory owned and/or writable by `www-data`

You could wrap your shell script in a [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) executable (e.g. code a small C program which would [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) your script) and `chmod u+srx` the compiled executable.

You might add (at least to ease debug) some [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) command to your script (and/or some [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) to your C program wrapping it), then look into messages under `/var/log/`

BTW, on a Rasberry Pi, you might replace your apache web server with a dedicated C program (e.g. using some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/))

Consider perhaps also [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) techniques (perhaps combined with [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)) on the browser side.